# Making a hexagon using circle formula

Tags: java, user-interface, geometry, draw

So I'm trying to make a hexagon using the points rsin(theta) and rcos(theta) formulas but seem to have some error in the formula. When writing it out on paper formula works but feel like I'm overlooking something....

```
public static void drawHexagon(double len, double xc, double yc, int angle)
{
    if(angle <= -360)
        angle = 0;
    double rotAngX = (len*Math.cos(angle));
    double rotAngY = (len*Math.sin(angle));
    //System.out.println(rotAngX + " " + rotAngY + " " + Math.cos(-30));
    /*double [] x = {(xc - len*(Math.sqrt(3)/2.0)), xc,
        xc + len*(Math.sqrt(3)/2.0), xc + len*(Math.sqrt(3)/2.0),
        xc, xc - len*(Math.sqrt(3)/2.0)};
    double [] y = {yc + len/2.0, yc + len, yc + len/2.0,
            yc - len/2.0, yc - len, yc - len/2.0};*/
    double[] x = new double[6];
    double[] y = new double[6];
    int[] angles = { 150, 90, 30, 330, 270, 210 };
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        x[i] = xc + (len*Math.cos(angles[i]));
        y[i] = yc + (len*Math.sin(angles[i]));
    }
    printPoints(x, y);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.CYAN);
    StdDraw.filledPolygon(x,y);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.PINK);
    StdDraw.polygon(x,y);
}
```

The section commented out works but I'm trying to rotate them, so in the for loop will be adding the angle parameter to angles[i]. What am I doing wrong in the for loop?

Here's the result of the code. Hexagon but not really:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/44qGN.png]

Comment: You don't need to hard-code the angles. `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { angle += 360.0 / 6; x=len*cos(angle); y=len*sin(angle); /* draw line to xc+x, yc+y */ }`

Comment: tried that but stil not showing as a hexagon

Comment: Math.cos and sin use radians

Comment: Ok, so it should be `angle += 2.0 * Math.PI / 6;`

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of Math.sin says:

> `public static double sin​(double a)`
>
> Returns the trigonometric sine of an angle. [...]
>
> Parameters:
>
> a - an angle, in radians.

Your code passes the angle in degrees rather than [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

You can either convert the angle first:

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30))
```

or directly specify the angle in radians:

```
Math.sin(Math.PI / 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but is it this?:

```
public static void drawHexagon(double len, double xc, double yc, int angle)
{
    double[] x = new double[6];
    double[] y = new double[6];  
    x[0] = len*Math.cos(3.14*angle/180.0);
    y[0] = len*Math.sin(3.14*angle/180.0);
    double cos_60; 
    double sin_60;
    cos_60 = 1.0/2.0;
    sin_60 = Math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        x[i] = xc + cos_60*x[i-1] - sin_60*y[i-1];
        y[i] = yc + sin_60*x[i-1] + cos_60*y[i-1];
    }
    printPoints(x, y);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.CYAN);
    StdDraw.filledPolygon(x,y);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(Color.PINK);
    StdDraw.polygon(x,y);
}
```